# Alias the AngularJS $scope object in a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Without getting into the details of why, I need to provide an alias for `$scope` in my controllers. Instead of injecting and decorating `$scope` I'd like for the users to instead be able to inject `view` and have it have the same effect.

Based on my understanding of angular, `$scope` is created by a `$scopeProvider` which is a factory registered at configuration time of the angular app. I'm assuming that I need to register a `viewProvider` and set it equal to the `$scopeProvider` but I haven't had luck with what I've been trying. Any ideas?

FYI: I'm not looking for something like `['$scope', function(view){...`, the ideal solution would work with `['view', function(view){...`. The view object would act *exactly* like `$scope`, two way binding, etc.

Comment: Using that alias do you want same things like two way binding as $scope does?

Comment: Yes. I want the same effect as having 'var view = $scope'

Comment: Expand on reason you want to mock a passive service. I can understand mocking am active service like http that reaches outside your sandbox. But the scope service is just a container for what you store in it and should be used the same way in uoir unit tests as in production.

Comment: We're providing a facility for semi-technical users to create simple controllers. A few have said that the `$scope` object is technical and confusing. I could create the same effect by adding `var view = $scope` but I don't want to require the users to add that line. It seems like I should be able to tell angular to treat the injectible `view` like `$scope`

Comment: I upvoted your question but avoid hiding what you really want to achieve. It changes everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it in my app's config section. In my controllers now I can use `$scope` or `view` and they'll have the same meaning.

```
   $routeProvider
    .when('/Index', {
        templateUrl: "/views/index.html",
        controller: ['$scope', '$controller', function($scope, $controller){
            $controller("IndexController", {$scope:$scope, view: $scope});
        }]
    })
```

Comment: but at last you are injecting `$scope` inside your `view` object

Comment: I'm injecting $scope as well so you can use either "$scope" or "view" to refer to the scope object. This is exactly what I wanted to do, have my real controller definition use "view" instead of '$scope' and have it mean the same thing.

Comment: then your question does ask something and you want something else

Comment: It was definately what I was asking. I wanted to be able to define controllers with `['view', function(view){....}]` and have view function exactly as $scope. With this change to my config I can now do that.

Comment: but I don't think see you are doing, basically you are adding your `$scope` to `view`, which is normal variable assignment, you could do it in your controller itself

Comment: I know this could be done in the controller, in fact I state that in my question text. My goal was not to do it in the controller (see the comments to the question for why I do not want to).

Answer (score 10):

If you are teaching `AngularJS`, you should actually avoid using `$scope` and use `controller as syntax` -- [See this awesome Angular Style Guide by John Papa for explanation](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y075).

That would also solve your problem :)

Comment: @Arbiter You are welcome :) Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such a thing as `$scopeProvider`, scopes are created using the `$new` method, every scope has access to this method through inheritance (delegation to be precise). When you ask for a `$scope` in a controller, the `$scope` is created dynamically using it's parent `$scope` `$new` method and injected under that name. To invoke the aforementioned behavior for a different name you would have to play with angular internals.